# wsdl2java axis2 error parsing wsdl caused nullpointerexception

Tags: java, service, nullpointerexception, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm new in using axis2 and I'trying to generate java classes from a wsdl.
Unfotunately I get the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:176)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:50)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:408)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:107)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:170)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:333)
        ... 4 more
```

I cannot figure out how to find the problem.

here is my wsdl :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <wsdl:definitions name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><wsdl:types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports"><xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:14560/?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/><xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:14560/?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/></xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_IsPortOpen_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IsPortOpen"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_IsPortOpen_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IsPortOpenResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_OpenPort_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:OpenPort"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_OpenPort_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:OpenPortResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_ClosePort_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ClosePort"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_ClosePort_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ClosePortResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_OpenSocket_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:OpenSocket"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_OpenSocket_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:OpenSocketResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_CloseSocket_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CloseSocket"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_CloseSocket_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CloseSocketResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SendToCOM_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendToCOM"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SendToCOM_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendToCOMResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SendToSocket_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendToSocket"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SendToSocket_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendToSocketResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SetPort_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetPort"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SetPort_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetPortResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetXmlRecieveState_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXmlRecieveState"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetXmlRecieveState_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXmlRecieveStateResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetXmlRecieve_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXmlRecieve"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetXmlRecieve_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXmlRecieveResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetXmlError_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXmlError"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_GetXmlError_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXmlErrorResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SetConfirmFlag_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetConfirmFlag"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SetConfirmFlag_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetConfirmFlagResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SetPrintFlag_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetPrintFlag"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="IService1_SetPrintFlag_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetPrintFlagResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="IService1"><wsdl:operation name="GetData"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="IsPortOpen"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/IsPortOpen" message="tns:IService1_IsPortOpen_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/IsPortOpenResponse" message="tns:IService1_IsPortOpen_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="OpenPort"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/OpenPort" message="tns:IService1_OpenPort_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/OpenPortResponse" message="tns:IService1_OpenPort_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="ClosePort"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/ClosePort" message="tns:IService1_ClosePort_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/ClosePortResponse" message="tns:IService1_ClosePort_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="OpenSocket"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/OpenSocket" message="tns:IService1_OpenSocket_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/OpenSocketResponse" message="tns:IService1_OpenSocket_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="CloseSocket"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/CloseSocket" message="tns:IService1_CloseSocket_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/CloseSocketResponse" message="tns:IService1_CloseSocket_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="SendToCOM"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SendToCOM" message="tns:IService1_SendToCOM_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SendToCOMResponse" message="tns:IService1_SendToCOM_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="SendToSocket"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SendToSocket" message="tns:IService1_SendToSocket_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SendToSocketResponse" message="tns:IService1_SendToSocket_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="SetPort"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SetPort" message="tns:IService1_SetPort_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SetPortResponse" message="tns:IService1_SetPort_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="GetXmlRecieveState"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetXmlRecieveState" message="tns:IService1_GetXmlRecieveState_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetXmlRecieveStateResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetXmlRecieveState_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="GetXmlRecieve"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetXmlRecieve" message="tns:IService1_GetXmlRecieve_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetXmlRecieveResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetXmlRecieve_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="GetXmlError"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetXmlError" message="tns:IService1_GetXmlError_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetXmlErrorResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetXmlError_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="SetConfirmFlag"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SetConfirmFlag" message="tns:IService1_SetConfirmFlag_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SetConfirmFlagResponse" message="tns:IService1_SetConfirmFlag_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation><wsdl:operation name="SetPrintFlag"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SetPrintFlag" message="tns:IService1_SetPrintFlag_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SetPrintFlagResponse" message="tns:IService1_SetPrintFlag_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:service name="Service1"/></wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: my service is run at localhost . i want to know where is my wsdl file have nullpointerexception ? thanks